# Удаление тега при загрузки страницы на малых экранах

Tags: javascript

нужна помощь, нужно удалить полностью тег при загрузки станицы,
пример такой, необходимо удалить `<section class="page4">` из станицы,

```
<div class="wrapper">
<section class="page1">...
</section>
<section class="page2">...
</section>
<section class="page3">...
</section>
<section class="page4">...
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: а если экран станет снова "больше"? например, если мы переворачиваем экран в горизонтальное положение на телефоне? как его вернуть?

Comment: Может лучше параметр `visible` менять?

Comment: у сайта блочный скролл получается, и если делать visible, или display none, то в этом 4 блоке все будет черным, все уберется, но он будет все рано, я так понимаю надо js кодом удалить этот 4 блок из html, тогда его не будет при определенном размере, примерно от размера планшета,простите возможно плохо объясняю всего пол года обучаюсь

Comment: вот исходник взят http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/purejs_onepage_scroll_demo.html

Comment: В случае с One Page Scroll, нужно удалить элемент, а затем заново инициализировать `$(".main").onepage_scroll();`. Тогда сработает. Но, как и писали выше, если экран увеличится, элемент не вернется